# React, Word Add-in - ClientAuthError: AcquireToken_In_Progress: Error during login call - login is already in progress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, office-js, azure-ad-msal, word-web-addins

I'm build a word plugin with react and the next step is to authenticate the user via MSAL.

[I've followed along with this tutorial](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-OfficeAddins/tree/master/Samples/auth/Office-Add-in-Microsoft-Graph-React).  I'm at a point where my relevant code looks identical to that code base.  That is:

`login.ts`
`login.html`
`office-api-helpers.ts`

My login button looks a little different but in essence we are both just pushing a button and kicking off the login process to `signInO365`.

If i use the sample code and import it with my manifest, and my client id everything works fine.  But when I try doing it from my code base I end up with the following error.

```
ClientAuthError: AcquireToken_In_Progress: Error during login call - login is already in progress.
at ClientAuthError.AuthError [as constructor] (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/msal/lib-es6/error/AuthError.js:25:28)
at new ClientAuthError (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/msal/lib-es6/error/ClientAuthError.js:110:28)
at Function.ClientAuthError.createAcquireTokenInProgressError (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/msal/lib-es6/error/ClientAuthError.js:154:16)
at UserAgentApplication.acquireTokenInteractive (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/msal/lib-es6/UserAgentApplication.js:292:238)
at UserAgentApplication.acquireTokenRedirect (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/msal/lib-es6/UserAgentApplication.js:236:14)
at Object.Office.initialize (webpack-internal:///../login/login.ts:45:26)
at OSF_InitializationHelper$prepareRightBeforeWebExtensionInitialize [as prepareRightBeforeWebExtensionInitialize] (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/word-web-16.00.debug.js:11326:32)
at https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.debug.js:1754:59
at validateFunction (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.debug.js:301:21)
```

I have been up and down this code trying to figure out where the issue could be but nothing seems to make sense.  What could be causing this?

Edit:

This happens when the user is trying to log into the account.  First the user opens the add in, then they are presented with the login button. That opens the dialog for Login.html. The user is then able to select an account and enter their credentials. After being redirected to microsoft then it looks like back to my redirect page (again, just login.html) is when the above message appears in the console of the dialog.

It seems to happen on `userAgentApp.acquireTokenRedirect(request);` if the user was previous logged in from the sample app or userAgentApp.loginRedirect(request); if not.

Edit 2 - whatever the issue was, it was in the latest (1.2.1) version.  I went back to 1.1.3 per the example and that resolved it.  Hope this helps someone else

Comment: Please clarify what steps lead up to the error and where/when you see the error.

Comment: I have also followed the example. The example currently comes with - "msal": "^1.1.3", and I am getting error: login is already in progress

Comment: @SteveTomlin I recommend you open a new question with your code as include the tag office-js and msal.  MSFT is supposed to be monitoring those tags but as you can see from the comment above its pretty hit or miss.  I will try to take a look as well if you share the new question

Comment: @nikolifish Thanks. I may do that.